# Checking for legitimate integer input in c++

Tags: c++, error-handling, integer, error-checking

so i've seen many people ask this and not many solid answers floating around the web. most just check that an integer was placed in place of a string but if a floating point number was entered then it truncates the bottom half or if integers and characters are intered it truncates the characters. i need help writing a piece of code that checks for user input and asks the user to retry if his input is not valid or a combination of valid/invalid. i think the basic idea was to make a string so it accepts anything then use sstream to manipulate and then back to int if the input was legit but i cant really manage to check the other parts. if anyones run accross this or can help me out please link me to it. i'll post my code when i get a good sense of what to do.

Comment: Boost's `lexical_cast` fails when converting double representations to integers.

Comment: i was hooping to not use external libraries since we are not allowed to install external libraries for assignments. btw still a student.

Comment: In that case, you can check whether the whole string was converted. I know there's a good example of that on here somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you can't use `boost::lexical_cast`, you can write your own version:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>
template <class T1, class T2>
T1 lexical_cast(const T2& t2)
{
  std::stringstream s;
  s << t2;
  T1 t1;
  if(s >> std::noskipws >> t1 && s.eof()) {
    // it worked, return result
    return t1;
  } else {
    // It failed, do something else:
    // maybe throw an exception:
    throw std::runtime_error("bad conversion");
    // maybe return zero:
    return T1();
    // maybe do something drastic:
    exit(1);
  }
}



int main() {
  std::string smin, smax;
  int imin, imax;

  while(std::cout << "Enter min and max: " && std::cin >> smin >> smax) {
    try {
      imin = lexical_cast<int>(smin);
      imax = lexical_cast<int>(smax);
      break;
    } catch(std::runtime_error&) {
      std::cout << "Try again: ";
      continue;
    }
  }

  if(std::cin) {
    std::cout << "Thanks!\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "Sorry. Goodbye\n";
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: this seems to be working but my understanding of what your doing is kinda off.

Comment: so this header accepts templates t2 and stores this in stringstream called s. you then declare t1 and in the if statement store s into noskipws (not sure what this does, i thought it was to count white space) and in turn store this in t1 as long as s has and end.

Comment: There is no "header". `lexical_cast` is a function template that, as you said, stores its argument `t2` into a `stringstream` and then extracts its return value `t1` from the same stringstream. Everything else is checking for error conditions.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in being wary of code that you do not understand. In academia, if you turn in homework that you cannot create independently, you are cheating. In the real world if you use code that you cannot understand, then you introduce bugs (or worse, trojans). In either case, the result is not good.

Answer (score 2):

You can use C++11 [string conversion functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) like stol

```
try
{
    std::string value = ...;
    long number = std::stol(value); 
}
catch (std::invalid_argument const& e)
{
    // no conversion could be performed
}
```

Post-comments update: Visual C++ 11 shipped with Visual Studio 2012 implements `std::stol` as a convenient wrapper around `strtol` declared in `<cstdlib>`. I think it's safe to assume most C++11 implementations define it in most optimal way possible, not reaching for `std::stringstream` machinery.

Comment: Any chance you've looked at how it is implemented? I haven't had a chance yet. Hopefully, not a string stream, but something more like `strtol`.

Comment: @VladLazarenko good point, I updated my answer based on my findings.

Answer (score 1):

The C function `strtol` (and it's siblings) will be able to tell you if the string fed to it is completely consumed.

```
 std::string str;
 char *endptr;
 std::cin >> str;
 long x = std::strtol(str.c_str(), &endptr, 0); 
 if (*endptr != 0) 
    cout << "That's not a valid number...";
```

Comment: this is saying that regular integers are also not numbers, also if a character or string is entered it kind of crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are any classes in standard c++ lib that encapsule primitive types like in java but here how a simple and very basic  implementation would look like

```
class Integer {
   private:
       int value;
       void parse(string);
   public:
       Integer(string);
       int intValue();
};

Integer::Integer(string sint) { parse(sint); }
int Integer::intValue() { return value; }

void Integer::parse(string sint) {
    string::iterator its = sint.begin();
    while(its != sint.end() && (! (*its < '0' || *its > '9'))) {
        its++;
    }
    if(its != sint.end()) {
        throw sint + ": Input is not a valid integer.";
    }
    value = atoi(sint.c_str());
}
```